# MySql count 3 tables with left join

Tags: mysql

Given the following 3 tables of video website database:

**video**

```
id    title
10    video1
```

**view** *(table for counting views of videos)*

```
id     userIP      videoId
1      1.1.1.1     10
2      2.2.2.2     10
```

**like** *(table for counting likes in videos)*

```
id     userID    videoId
1      1001      10
```

I want to write MYSQL query to count views and likes for each video, so in that example i should receive:

```
videoId    views     likes
10         2         1
```

I tried to run the following query, but it displayed wrong output:

```
SELECT V.id, count(VW.id) as views, count(L.id) as likes
FROM video V 
     LEFT JOIN view VW
ON VW.videoId = V.id
     LEFT JOIN `like` L
ON L.videoId = V.id
WHERE V.id=10
GROUP BY V.id, VW.id, L.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, see that I only count once per query

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(videoId) FROM view WHERE videoId=10) as view,
  (SELECT COUNT(videoId) FROM like WHERE videoId=10) as like;
```